# D3 JS - How to set maximum length of links in force graph?

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create a simple force graph. Graph contains nodes and links and not any labels. I came across this weird issue in which length of links is increasing automatically when I group some nodes at one position. Nodes are sticky. When I drag and place nodes at upper left side then other non sticky nodes goes down right side and length of links also increases. 
Is there any way I can set maximum length of links? Code is given below.

Or is there any force to control this kind of behavior?

```js
    //create somewhere to put the force directed graph
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        width = +svg.attr("width"),
        height = +svg.attr("height");

    //d3 code goes here
    //Characters
    var nodes_data = [{
        "name": "Lillian",
        "sex": "F"
    }, {
        "name": "Gordon",
        "sex": "M"
    }, {
        "name": "Sylvester",
        "sex": "M"
    }, {
        "name": "Mary",
        "sex": "F"
    }, {
        "name": "Helen",
        "sex": "F"
    }, {
        "name": "Jamie",
        "sex": "M"
    }, {
        "name": "Jessie",
        "sex": "F"
    }, {
        "name": "Ashton",
        "sex": "M"
    }, {
        "name": "Duncan",
        "sex": "M"
    }, {
        "name": "Evette",
        "sex": "F"
    }, {
        "name": "Mauer",
        "sex": "M"
    }, {
        "name": "Fray",
        "sex": "F"
    }, {
        "name": "Duke",
        "sex": "M"
    }, {
        "name": "Baron",
        "sex": "M"
    }, {
        "name": "Infante",
        "sex": "M"
    }, {
        "name": "Percy",
        "sex": "M"
    }, {
        "name": "Cynthia",
        "sex": "F"
    }]

    //Relationships
    //type: A for Ally, E for Enemy
    var links_data = [{
            "source": "Sylvester",
            "target": "Gordon",
            "type": "A"
        }, {
            "source": "Sylvester",
            "target": "Lillian",
            "type": "A"
        }, {
            "source": "Sylvester",
            "target": "Mary",
            "type": "A"
        }, {
            "source": "Sylvester",
            "target": "Jamie",
            "type": "A"
        }, {
            "source": "Sylvester",
            "target": "Jessie",
            "type": "A"
        }, {
            "source": "Sylvester",
            "target": "Helen",
            "type": "A"
        }, {
            "source": "Helen",
            "target": "Gordon",
            "type": "A"
        }, {
            "source": "Mary",
            "target": "Lillian",
            "type": "A"
        }, {
            "source": "Ashton",
            "target": "Mary",
            "type": "A"
        }, {
            "source": "Duncan",
            "target": "Jamie",
            "type": "A"
        }, {
            "source": "Gordon",
            "target": "Jessie",
            "type": "A"
        }, {
            "source": "Sylvester",
            "target": "Fray",
            "type": "E"
        }, {
            "source": "Fray",
            "target": "Mauer",
            "type": "A"
        }, {
            "source": "Fray",
            "target": "Cynthia",
            "type": "A"
        }, {
            "source": "Fray",
            "target": "Percy",
            "type": "A"
        }, {
            "source": "Percy",
            "target": "Cynthia",
            "type": "A"
        }, {
            "source": "Infante",
            "target": "Duke",
            "type": "A"
        }, {
            "source": "Duke",
            "target": "Gordon",
            "type": "A"
        }, {
            "source": "Duke",
            "target": "Sylvester",
            "type": "A"
        }, {
            "source": "Baron",
            "target": "Duke",
            "type": "A"
        }, {
            "source": "Baron",
            "target": "Sylvester",
            "type": "E"
        }, {
            "source": "Evette",
            "target": "Sylvester",
            "type": "E"
        }, {
            "source": "Cynthia",
            "target": "Sylvester",
            "type": "E"
        }, {
            "source": "Cynthia",
            "target": "Jamie",
            "type": "E"
        }, {
            "source": "Mauer",
            "target": "Jessie",
            "type": "E"
        }]
        //set up the simulation 
        //nodes only for now 
    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .nodes(nodes_data);

    //add forces
    //we're going to add a charge to each node 
    //also going to add a centering force
    simulation
        .force("charge_force", d3.forceManyBody().strength([-400]))
        .force("center_force", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
        .on("tick", tickActions);

    //draw lines for the links 
    var link = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "links")
        .selectAll("line")
        .data(links_data)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("stroke-width", 3)
        .attr("stroke", linkColour);

    function linkColour(d) {
        if (d.type == "A") {
            return "green";
        } else {
            return "red";
        }
    }

    //draw circles for the nodes 
    var node = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nodes")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(nodes_data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 15)
        .attr("fill", circleColour);

    function circleColour(d) {
        if (d.sex == "M") {
            return "blue";
        } else {
            return "pink";
        }
    }

    //Create the link force 
    //We need the id accessor to use named sources and targets 
    var link_force = d3.forceLink(links_data)
        .id(function(d) {
            return d.name;
        });

    //Add a links force to the simulation
    //Specify links  in d3.forceLink argument   
    simulation.force("links", link_force);

    // setup drag handler
    var drag_handler = d3.drag()
        .on("start", drag_start)
        .on("drag", drag_drag)
        .on("end", drag_end);

    //same as using .call on the node variable as in https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045 
    drag_handler(node)

    //drag handler
    //d is the node 
    function drag_start(d) {
        if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
        d.fx = d.x;
        d.fy = d.y;
    }

    function drag_drag(d) {
        d.fx = d3.event.x;
        d.fy = d3.event.y;
    }

    // // for non sticky behaviour
    // function drag_end(d) {
    //     if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    //     d.fx = null;
    //     d.fy = null;
    // }

    // // for sticky behaviour
    function drag_end(d) {
        if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
        d.fx = d.x;
        d.fy = d.y;
    }

    // // Sticky nodes on x axis
    // function drag_end(d) {
    //     if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    //     d.fx = d.x;
    //     d.fy = null;
    // }

    // // Sticky nodes on y axis
    // function drag_end(d) {
    //     if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    //     d.fx = null;
    //     d.fy = d.y;
    // }

    // // Fixed node position on dragged
    // function drag_end(d) {
    //     if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    //     d.fx = 300;
    //     d.fy = 200;
    // }

    // Invert node position on dragged
    // function drag_end(d) {
    //     if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    //     d.fx = d.y;
    //     d.fy = d.x;
    // }

    function tickActions() {
        //update circle positions to reflect node updates on each tick of the simulation 
        node
            .attr("cx", function(d) {
                return d.x;
            })
            .attr("cy", function(d) {
                return d.y;
            });

        //update link positions 
        //simply tells one end of the line to follow one node around
        //and the other end of the line to follow the other node around
        link
            .attr("x1", function(d) {
                return d.source.x;
            })
            .attr("y1", function(d) {
                return d.source.y;
            })
            .attr("x2", function(d) {
                return d.target.x;
            })
            .attr("y2", function(d) {
                return d.target.y;
            });
    }
```

```css
 .links line {
        /* stroke: #999; */
        stroke-opacity: 0.6;
    }
    
    .nodes circle {
        stroke: #fff;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<h2>Draggable force graph with sticky nodes and other behaviours of node positioning</h2>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
```

Comment: don't use forceCenter but forceX and forceY

Comment: do you still want the nodes to be static after the drag and drop? or do you want to enforce a minimum distance between the nodes? Note that the nodes positioning is a dynamic parameter calculated by the simulation

Comment: Thanks rioV8. This is working. Graph is not rendering at center now and thats the issue.

Comment: cal_br_mar - After dragging the node, its link length should be fixed. It just that it should not  increase.